# On database communication security

Tags: database, security, ssl, tcp, connection

So, I've been reading about security in relation to desktop applications and database servers. Previously when I've built applications that are linked to a database, I've taken the easy route and simply stored the connection string hard coded in the source code directly. This has worked since the binaries were not distributed to third parties. However, now I'm working on a project whose binaries are bound for third party use, and in this case the communication with the server becomes a security issue that I need to deal with.

Since it is a priority that there be no direct connection to the remote database from the client machine, I understand that a server/client database service is a good choice. In this case, the client machine sends requests using TCP to a server, which then processes the request using stored procedures and responds accordingly to the client.

My questions in relation to this are:

i. Would this setup be an advisable one, or are other setups of which I am unaware more advisable for the kind of project I am working on?

ii. How does one go about securing such a connection? I can easily set up an SSL connection to the server using a security certificate generated by OpenSSL, however I'm not sure whether this is the correct way of securing the connection for a desktop application, or whether this method is primarily used for HTTPS. And WHEN should one in general secure the connection (are there instances where this wouldn't matter, for instance if all I do is send booleans back and forth?)? Any good resources that discuss these issues? For instance, I have a lot of application installed on my Windows PC that are networked, but I don't see many of them installing a security certificate on my PC. What gives?

Full disclosure: I'm a C++ (hobbyist) programmer using Boost libraries for my network programming needs and OpenSSL for my SSL cryptography. However, I hope this can be answered without paying too much attention to these facts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

i. Having your application talk to a web service that then talks to the database is a better setup.   This abstracts the database away from the clients (and therefore direct access from the internet).

ii. This depends on what the threats to your system are.  If the data you are vending from the web service mentioned above is data that is not sensitive, and is not user specific (say an app that allows searching of public photo galleries, so your web service simply returns a result set with URLs) then you might be able to get by with simply using SSL.  Other apps get around installing their own cert in a myriad of ways.  They can either get a cert from a CA like verisign, so your computer already trusts it.  Or they can deploy the public cert with the binary of their app, and handle it inside of their app (this is a form of certificate pinning).

ii part 2.  If you need the clients to authenticate, for reasons of either wanting to make sure that not just anyone can use your web service, or to support a more advanced authorization model, then you would need to implement some sort of authentication.  That would be a much bigger question to address.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The application in question will utilize some form of user authentication, so your recommendation will definitely be followed. I think I'll go hunting for books on this topic. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use CA-signed certificates, and not self-signed. You might also want to consider mutual authentication between your service and the database.